# ResultSet with binary data

Tags: java, resultset

I have a simple Java 6 code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db?user=u&password=p");
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tabela);

 while(res.next()){
     byte[] fileBytes = res.getBytes(fileColumnIndex);
     fos.write(fileBytes);
 }
```

So my question is - does ResultSet load all data to some local memory at once, or does it load it by chunks on every res.next()?

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

You are moving through your result from the executed SQL query, row by row, column by column (by the index or the column name)

(Don't forget to free resources when you are done with your result set).

About your question, consider as a programmer the ResultSet as the same concept to the Stream: "you can't do anything about the past, you don't know the future, you can only process the present"